# Rails - Multi tenant application with customization framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, multi-tenant

I am organizing a multi tenant application with a single code base/application using subdomains to detect the tenant, then runs a SET SCHEMA on postgres to do the fun stuff.

My issue is that certain clients will require various levels of customization to the main codebase. Not a ton, but certainly enough to the point that I wouldn't want to start hacking the main models and controllers by adding a bunch of if statements.

Overriding views is easy enough with views load paths...  but my question is: How can I provide a good framework for overriding or adding functionality to the base controllers, models and helpers to tweak things for each tenant as needed? Ideally it should be pretty seamless and not invasive to the main code, and should provide a decent mechanism for organizing the customized code.

I've investigated a few options, including using includes/extends (mixins). The issue is that in production, methods stay in the objects (understandable). I've tried hte mixology gem to work around this, but it doesn't totally work as I had intended and its a bit more invasive than I'd like it to be, I'm also unclear how to relate it to models (in the controllers I just tried mixin/unmix via before/after filters).

If anybody has any ideas on how to best approach/solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your feedback. FWIW this is Rails3

Comment: [Related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641653/multiple-applications-using-a-single-code-base-in-ruby). Curious to know if you've nailed it since.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about switching databases on the fly between requests then I think you're in for a world of hurt, at least when it comes to using ActiveRecord. This will mess up the caching system severely as it remembers things based on ID, not ID + Schema, which could result in cross-contamination.

Generally, from an architectural perspective, it's best to partition your database internally and have every record scoped accordingly. For instance:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Represents a site or installation of the application
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
end
```

Link everything up to the main `Site` record, or whatever term would best describe the method you use to partition. Maintaining a consistent scope is far easier than switching schema.

If, for reasons of scaling, you want to split the database in the future, if you've been careful to tag all of a site's associated records with a consistent `site_id` column, you can easily transpose all of these records to a new database.

Comment: Tadman,Thanks for the response. The database isn't really the issue, nor is cross contamination. I won't be switching databases on the fly, I will be using postgres's schema functionality and select the schema with an around filter, which should be fine. And since i'm not multithreading, it should be fine and free of cross contamination. You can actually see a proof of this by Guy Naor of Morph Labs at acts_as_conference 2009: http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/03/26/acts_as_conference-2009-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails. My issue is more related to customizing functionality.

Comment: For various reasons, including but not limited to security, scoping a site_id in shared tables is not an option. I would also think that is more prone to "mistakes" crossing cross contamination than postgres's schemas.

Comment: The most reliable way is to have separate deployments with different `database.yml` files for each instance, which if managed through a load-balancing front end like Passenger isn't as bad as it sounds. Maybe I'm more old-school in this sense. I'll have a look at that video.

Comment: The issue isn't the data. Additionally, separating the data via different databases isn't desirable. This would require me to manage instances on a client level which would be a PITA to scale properly (some clients are hot, some are not, etc). Regarding data, the most effective approach in my situation is pg schemas. As I've pointed out, my issue is specifically regarding customization for each client. This means alterations to controllers, models, and views (overriding default MVC's on a tenant level without creating an entirely separate application)

Comment: I guess I'm as curious as you to see what the answer to this is, then.

Answer (score 0):

Would a hooks + plugins setup meet your needs?  ie: build the additional functionality into another model, on whatever actions you need to modify check a hooks table to see if the user requires any extra actions, hooks table also specifies the action to take so you could easily setup different configurations for different users.

If you found a better answer to this please update.

Comment: Actually, this is very similar to the approach I ended up taking. The code needs to be refined, but it seems to work. Basically I define new methods for a class in a database (including the code for the method), or redefine a method in the database. At runtime, it checks to see if a revised action or a new action exists given the context, and runs the eval code. In the case of redefined actions, i create an alias to the old action, then un-alias it when the request completes--- which should work fine in single thread environments.