# Multiple applications using a single code base in ruby

Tags: ruby, multi-tenant

I'm trying to get a reasonable understanding of how one can build an app on top of ruby/rack (or even more ideally, an existing framework) that manages something equivalent to WordPress. Specifically, with the ability to serve multiple sites from the same code base, each with its own features and configuration.

Suppose, for instance:

- example.com using auth, pages, blog modules
- forum.example.com -> auth, forum modules
- api.example.com -> auth, api modules

This test case seems to work, including in a production environment:

```
# test.rb
class Foo
end

# config.ru
require 'rack'

use Rack::ShowExceptions
use Rack::CommonLogger

run lambda { |env|
  case env['HTTP_HOST']
  when /^test\./
    require './test'
    # answers true, regardless of subdomain loaded first
    [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, "#{Kernel.const_defined? :Foo}"]
  else
    # answers false, regardless of subdomain loaded first
    [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, "#{Kernel.const_defined? :Foo}"]
  end
}
```

Having mostly worked in environments with little if any state until now, however, I'm a bit nervous that this might come back and bite me down the road.

At any rate, what did I miss/where should I expect it to come back and bite me? (Performance due to file reloads? DB connection pools that need to be re-initialized if appropriate? Sessions being invalidly shared across different domains? etc. besides the obvious fact that any caching as static files will be inappropriate.)

And, is there any app around that allows to do this out of the box?

(My initial impression with Rails was that it won't fit for such a use-case. Perhaps wrongly. The only multisite plugin I ran into was to allow example.com/site1, example.com/site2, etc.)

---

These two threads exemplify what I'm worried about:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823125/rails-multi-tenant-resource-loading
- [Rails - Multi tenant application with customization framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858946/rails-multi-tenant-application-with-customization-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've probably overcomplicated the situation somewhat. You can easily point different subdomains to different Rails applications using your web server configuration. For example in Nginx, you'd simply create different virtual hosts.

If you want all the modules contained in one application, then you can have a single virtual host with a wildcard subdomain, and use the routing in your Rails app to route via subdomain to different parts of your app. This would lend itself very well to an [Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) architecture.

With regards databases, in the first example there's no problem at all as the different apps can handle their own database connections. With the engine example, typically engines tables would be in the same database but namespaced.

**Edit** - my answer is specifically talking about Rails, whereas your question was more generic.

Comment: Back when I had asked the question, I was looking into building something akin to WordPress multi-user: one code base, multiple sites, one database, a master users table, and a set of database tables per site (rather than carrying a site_id all over the place).

Comment: Ah, a typical multitenant set up then. You threw me with your forum.xyz.com, api.xyz.com.. (which is a different idea completely). I will edit my answer.

Comment: the forum.domain and api.domain parts are actually relevant too: they could be rails engines, but for all intents and purposes they'd be plugins in the WP world. :-)

Comment: How would the different tenants be distinguished if not by subdomain?

Comment: By subdomains. What WP allows in this case is to use a different set of plugins per subdomain. This is possible because PHP is reloaded on every page view. As I understood things when I asked the question, this isn't the case for a Rails app, meaning that once an engine is loaded, for instance, it's enabled for all subsequent requests to that app.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following. If the tenant is identified by the subdomain, for example: `mikecampbell.domain.com`, how does `forum.domain.com` fit in?

Comment: Suppose that on your subdomain, you decide to run a forum; you'd enable the forum-oriented stuff. And on your other subdomain, you'd want a store. You'd enable store-oriented features. At the end-user level, you could create a new subdomain. And you could put whatever types of features you'd want on it, much like you can on hosted CMS solutions. (At any rate, no worries if there is no solution to speak of in Rubyland, as it's fine too. This is a project I was looking into two years ago, and your own question prompted me to ask if things might have changed since I last looked.)

Comment: Sounds like what I first thought it was, that is not multitenancy as there's only one "user", that's just different "modules" or application functionality that you'd like to associate with each subdomain. Therefore my answer still stands as it is, but you'd want some extra logic introduced to decide which engines/modules are enabled or not, and also some way to assign them to arbitrary subdomains, which is all possible.