# Rails multitenant architecture, scoping access to multiple tenants

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, multi-tenant

We have a single-tenant database architecture at the moment with MySQL running upward of 100 databases. We switch database connection on subdomain using the Apartment gem and all is dandy!

However, we have a requirement now to create so-called "Umbrella" clients which can access all the data from a group of our existing clients. I don't see this as immediately feasible with our single-tenant database architecture (I looked into it and querying multiple MySQL databases just seemed hellish), so I'm beginning to look at different implementations with Postgres schemas.

I'm looking for some advice:

- is it possible to query multiple schemas in Postgres and collate the results somehow (looking for Rails implementation)? I can foresee problems with conflicting primary keys?
- Would it be better to have a new schema that is somehow
  represents/duplicates all the data in the group of schemas that need
  to be accessed? It would need to be realtime.
- If so, can something similar be achieved in my current multiple DB
  set-up with MySQL? (to minimise the pain)

I'm wary of using a database field to achieve multitenancy in MySQL as data security/privacy is a huge thing for this product, and there's so much potential for developer error that way.

Comment: Possibly related threads in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641653/multiple-applications-using-a-single-code-base-in-ruby

Comment: Tahnks. I understand how to achieve a multitenant application in Rails quite clearly, it's the concept of having an "umbrella" tenant that can access multiple other tenants which is where I'm struggling.

Comment: Multiple Postgres schemas are way better than multiple MySQL databases. You should be able to query any schema in the database you have access to, there's no need to explicitly switch. I hope someone's got an answer with a stock gem that does it.

Comment: @MikeCampbell: if you have a good answer to my two year old question, please share. :-)

Comment: @tadman, so you suggest cycling though the postgres schemas and querying each one individually? I assume this is quite quick? I'll look into it!

Comment: Probably the best way to implement is to add the "umbrella" users to each database (or some sort of central authentication) and force the user to login to the correct tenant.

Comment: @cpuguy83: you don't realise how much I'd like that to be a suitable solution, but unfortunately it isn't. All the data needs to be collated into a single system.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to bring it all in to a single scheme and assign domain id's to each record, and the list of domains a user has access to.

Comment: @cpuguy83, I'm swaying toward this at the moment, but I'm thinking of writing some way to take the responsibility of specifying the client scope out of the hands of the developer. Paranoid about someone forgetting to scope something.

Comment: What I do in my pseudo-multitenant app is I have setup a model which stores configurable scopes which can be edited from inside the app itself and each controller uses it as an authorization scope and filters out per user/group what I do not want them to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just thinking through this on a high level approach to this problem.

You could create a pg [view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createview.html) table to access this data (although it *will* be slower than accessing the databases themselves).

Then you hopefully have enough unique fields in your table to create a compound or composite key. (Then you wouldn't have to create a new key column, just an index). Because Rails 3 is ORM agnostic, you could then use DataMapper (or maybe the new ROM gem) to establish the connection for this one model.

If you do compound keys, realize that you might have to explicitly define the *to_param* method in your model to build the key as a string. This is for unwrapping the :id when you send it in a url.

You can setup access to this view through a different Postgres user and then use Rails' ability for multiple connections to create a model for it. We did this previously to aggregate data from multiple tables with some restrictions on what was being shown, but I don't see why that wouldn't apply in your use case.

Another option is that perhaps you could use Mongo as the "transient query database". BSON would give you unique keys automatically. And you could create Objects that are essentially SQL Scalar Objects. Not sure you'd want to do a write back to the original database in this case though... but you feasibly could do it.

Bottom line IMO is I think the best solution lies on the database side of the house because you're using multiple databases. Dealing with these items at the database layer seems the best solution.

Having said all of this... this also seems like a process smell. If I read the problem as stated correctly, I think what you're really trying to do in this case is what [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is designed for... essentially map/reduce of relevant data (aka Big Data Analysis)

Good luck!

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hoping for, plenty of food for thought. Seeing as this is a fairly long term thing for us I'm not going to hang around to see what we do before accepting an answer, this one gets the big fat tick for addressing my question most accurately. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Despite finding many examples of multitenancy in Rails applications when I first set out to do it, I couldn't find one that made me felt completely comfortable either.  But I finally have a solution I'm happy with.

I started with the 'multitenancy with scopes' railscast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

then looked at making multi-tenancy work with devise subdomains using this guide:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Isolate-users-to-log-into-a-single-subdomain

But I didn't take that at face value; I dove in to really understand how devise worked that way.

Once I had all that in place, I was ready for the multitenant gem:

https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant

But I didn't stop there.  the multitenant gem requires that you say Multitenant.with_tenant whenever you want things scoped appropriatey, so I created a TenantController that looks like this:

```
  around_filter :scope_current_tenant

  def scope_current_tenant
    begin
      Firm.current = Firm.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
    rescue
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end

    Multitenant.with_tenant Firm.current do
      yield
    end

    ensure
      Firm.current = nil
    end
  end
```

and then any controller I want to be scoped by tenant inherits from TenantController rather than ApplicationController.  That way I didn't have to remember anything in the details of the controller, it 'just worked'.  the only thing developers had to think about was 'is this a controller that is handling tenant data?'

While this still depends on developers doing a few things correctly (inheriting from the right controller, saying 'acts_as_multitenant' in the model, it works really well in practice.

Comment: This is of value with regards to my concerns about multitenancy with scopes, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

OBS: I'm not a Ruby guy, so I can only give you the PG side of the idea.

With PostgreSQL schemas you can easily manage it. Just create a schema for each tenant you have, so in you application, when you need to change the tenant you just do:

```
SET search_path TO client1;
```

With that, when you query for a table, let's say `customer`, you only need to do on the same connection:

```
SELECT ... FROM customer ...;
```

And, when you need to query for another tenant (not in `search_path`) you can query the table with the schema:

```
SELECT ... FROM client2.customer ...;
```

And you can use another schema to store public information, like the `public` schema, just adding it to the end of `search_path`:

```
SET search_path TO client1, public;
```

Comment: you don't specifically answer my question about on how to architect this "umbrella" application collating data of multiple tenants, which was the crux of my question. I know how to use schemas fairly well already, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Depending on the amount of tenants you can easily `UNION ALL` your tables from different schemas or even PG's inheritance. But, for many tenants it can become a performance problem. Another solution is to use `tenant_id` (or something like) columns and views on the tenants schemas, if it is a good idea for a Rails app I may explain better.

Answer (score -3):

Hate to say it since it sounds like you're already quite invested in your current system but it sounds like a job that would be better suited for a NoSQL solution.

Specifically, I'm thinking of MongoDB which uses a "schemaless", key-value database design. This would enable you pull data from your database based on a key and sort it in software. MongoDB also supports sharding which lets you use one database across as many database servers as you want, which sounds like it could work well in you application. The docs at http://www.mongodb.org/ might be worth checking. I'm not sure if it would be a perfect fit but it sounds like it could work for your application.

Comment: If it's worth considering then I'll consider it! Any specific reasons why? I have almost no experience with NoSQL so would love to know more.

Comment: Switching from a full RDBMS like Postgres to a schemaless MongoDB is not a trivial task. Also, MongoDB is not a silver bullet here and might even make securing the application far more difficult than partitioning by schema or database.