# Rails collating data from multiple schemas on Multitenant application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-schema, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

Before I set out on a big structural change in my app, I would like to know a bit more about the basics of multi-tentant apps implemented with Postgres' schemas in Rails.

More objectively: I would like to know how to query accross schemas.

Say I have two schemas, for two different customers, both containing a "Sales" model, and I need to grab an average sales amount. How does that work?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279141/rails-multitenant-architecture-scoping-access-to-multiple-tenants) but honestly it kinda felt like rocket science to me.

I was thinking that there had to be a simple way to have something like an "admin" tenant that would be able to aggregate info from all tenants in an easy and transparent way... am I very very wrong?